# Convergence of a mixed distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

> Let $Y_n=Z+\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{1/i^2}$, with $\delta$ a point mass and $L(Z)=N(0,\sigma^2)$. Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} Y_n=Y$, where $L(Y)=N(\frac{\pi^2}{6},\sigma^2)$

The answer file uses Cauchy-sequences to proof this, but I'd like to use MGFs to proof this. My guess was:

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{tY_n}]=\int_\mathbb{R} e^{ty_n} \mu_{Y_n}(dy_n)$$
$$=\int_\mathbb{R} e^{ty_n} (\mu_Z+\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_\frac{1}{i^2})(dy_n)$$
$$=\int_\mathbb{R} e^{ty_n} \mu_Z(dy_n)+\int_\mathbb{R}e^{ty_n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\delta_\frac{1}{i^2})(dy_n)$$
$$=e^{\frac{1}{2}t^2\sigma^2}+\int_\mathbb{R}e^{ty_n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\delta_\frac{1}{i^2})(dy_n)$$

This is where I am stuck. I don't possibly see how this could go to $N(\frac{\pi^2}{6},\sigma^2)$. Indeed, $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2}=\pi^2/6$
, but that's the only link I see. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Here $\delta$ are not measures but merely constant r.v.s? If not then I do not understand the setup, because you cannot add probability measures to get a new probability measure without renormalizing.

Comment: $\delta$ is a measure, not a constant indeed.

Comment: Never mind, got it! I should have used: $M_{Y_n}(t)=M_{Z}(t)M_{\delta_1}M_{\delta_\frac{1}{4}}\dots$.

Comment: If these are measures then the sum is not a probability measure...or is your $+$ addition of corresponding r.v.s instead of addition of measures?